# How to convert array of object property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, frontend

I'm trying to convert array of objects having value as a array -> into string. I'm facing blocker in this,

```
    let peopleDetails = [
     {
       name: "raj",
       favCar: [{ name: "audi", color: "white" }],
       favFood: [{ color: "brown", name: "Idli" }],
     },
     { name: "deepak", place: "India", favPlace: [{ name: "Tajmahal" }] },
    ];
```

I need structure like,

```
    let peopleDetails = [
     { name: "raj", favCar: "audi", favFood: "Idli" },
     { name: "deepak", place: "India", favPlace: "Tajmahal" },
    ];
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+group+object+array+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Is it by design that you don't want everything? Like in the example you are missing the `color: "White"` from the car.

Comment: @nbjorling I want name only

Answer (score 1):

For what I understand you want the value of every property to become the `name` value of its first element, when the value is an array of object.

Here's an immutable solution that follows this concept:

```js
let peopleDetails = [
    {
        name: 'raj',
        favCar: [{ name: 'audi', color: 'white' }],
        favFood: [{ name: 'Idli' }],
    },
    { name: 'deepak', place: 'India', favPlace: [{ name: 'Tajmahal' }] },
];


const result = peopleDetails.map(obj => 
  Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => 
    [key, value?.[0]?.name ?? value]
  ))
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Yes, I want every property to become a name. but not necessary to become first element.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you've got arrays of singular elements (favourites typically don't have second or third places) so if you just want to extract the `name` from each item that's an array, take it from the first element in each array:

```js
let peopleDetails = [{
    name: "raj",
    favCar: [{
      name: "audi",
      color: "white"
    }],
    favFood: [{
      name: "Idli"
    }],
  },
  {
    name: "deepak",
    place: "India",
    favPlace: [{
      name: "Tajmahal"
    }]
  },
];

let peopleDetailsModified = peopleDetails.map(o => {
  let retObj = {};
  for (key in o) {
    if (Array.isArray(o[key])) {
      retObj[key] = o[key][0].name;
    } else {
      retObj[key] = o[key];
    }
  }
  return retObj;
});

console.log(peopleDetailsModified);
```

<sub>I've made this code more verbose than it needs to be, it's quite easy to one-line it using `reduce`.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I'm also quite not sure what you're trying to achieve as the other answers but I tried to make a map of the current object to an object that is more to your liking. I formatted it a little so you can see what I did:

```
peopleDetails.map(item =>  {
return {
name: item.name, 
place: item.place, 
favCar: item.favCar ? item.favCar[0].name : "", 
favPlace: item.favPlace ? item.favPlace[0].name : "", 
favFood: item.favFood ? item.favFood[0].name : ""}});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have ran the code and its a generic code for similar data

```
const _ = require('lodash')
const peopleDetails =[
  {
    "name": "raj",
    "favCar": [
      {
        "name": "audi",
        "color": "white"
      }
    ],
    "favFood": [
      {
        "name": "Idli"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "deepak",
    "place": "India",
    "favPlace": [
      {
        "name": "Tajmahal"
      }
    ]
  }
]

const newPeopleDetails = peopleDetails.map(obj => {
    const formObj = {
        favCar: obj && obj.favCar && obj.favCar[0].name,
        favFood: obj && obj.favFood && obj.favFood[0].name,
        favPlace: obj && obj.favPlace && obj.favPlace[0].name
      }
      const finalObj = _.pickBy(formObj, _.identity);
  return Object.assign({}, obj, finalObj);
});
console.log(newPeopleDetails)
```